# Adding an older version of EF to a project

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, entity

I have an older C# Silverlight 5 application (in visual studio 2012) that has some supporting data access projects using EF5.  Looking at them I see just an edmx and when viewing in the Solution Explorer  and expanding it I see a Designer.cs file.  Expanding this I can see all the entities.  Nuget shows EF 5.0.0 associated to the project.  Looking at the actual reference, I see Runtime version v4.0.30319, Version 4.4.0.0.

Now, updating EF isn't a possibility (too much at stake) but when I Add a New Item of type 'ADO.NET Entity Data Model', I see what appears to be EF 6 items (Context.tt, Designer.cs, edmx.diagram, .tt) added.  Regardless, it's not the same as the other existing data access projects that use EF.

Is there a way to just add the edmx and the designer.cs files (same as the original EF stuff) a different way?
Please let me know if you require any additional clarification!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the assistance, but what I finally had to do was this:

Because the project was originally created in VS2010 (then later converted to 2012), I created a new project and added a new item (ADO.NET Entity Data Model).  After making the connection and adding entities through the wizard everything looked as it should within the 2010 project.  I was showing just an .edmx, and a Designer.cs with entities listed within. From my 2012 project I 'added an existing item', and selected the .edmx file from the 2010 project.  The Designer.cs gets created automatically and everything that I needed is working and looks just like all the other edmx files.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj613116.aspx) explains how to download different EF package versions.

Also, VS2012 uses the EF 5.x DbContext Generator by default...

[image]